# Android Paid App and Free App

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish an app on play store, there will free app with limited features and pro version with all features which will be paid.
Do I have to create two different Apps on play store or I can do it in one app only?

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways.  One is to make the upgrade be an in app purchase.  Then you only have 1 app and they use the app to buy the upgrade.  The other is to have 2 separate apps.  Then you need 2 apps in the play store.  I would suggest method 1, its easier to guide the user to that option.  The more steps the user has to take, the less likely they are to buy.